# pre-receive hook on server-side that refuse any push to master which has any non-linear history

Tags: git, sh

I am looking for a shell script (`sh`, not `bash` possibly) that would refuse any push to *master* which has any non-linear history.

I tried script from:

[How to avoid "Merge branch 'master' of ssh://gdcm.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/gdcm/gdcm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482887/how-to-avoid-merge-branch-master-of-ssh-gdcm-git-sourceforge-net-gitroot-gdc)

which is implemented in `ruby`, but it does not even run on [sourceforge](http://sf.net) server. I tried then the bash equivalent:

https://fedorahosted.org/fedora-infrastructure/attachment/ticket/1342/pre-receive

this one runs, but does not do what it is supposed to do (it does not reject anything).

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much, much more simply than your hook.

```
merge_commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 --merges $rev_old..$rev_new)
if [ -n "$merge_commit" ]; then
     echo "Merge commit detected: $merge_commit";
     exit 1
fi
```

You also might want to make this an update hook, not a pre-receive hook. The pre-receive hook runs once for the entire push, taking input on stdin, while the update hook runs once per ref to be updated, taking input as arguments. That gives you better granularity.

```
#!/bin/sh
ref=$1
rev_old=$2
rev_new=$3
if [ "$ref" = refs/heads/master ]; then
    ...
fi
```

There's also usually no need to check for fast forwards. Git already by default disallows non-fast-forward pushes, and if you want to deny them even on forced pushes, just set `receive.denyNonFastForwards` to true in the config. I guess you want to deny them even for forced pushes to master, but allow them elsewhere? That's a kind of access control that's actually implemented very well by things like gitolite, if you're doing your own hosting, but I guess if that's your requirement and you don't have gitolite, this is the best you can do.

Finally, it also strikes me as odd that you'll allow merge commits to be pushed to other refs, just not master. That could lead to some surprises, if someone pushes to an unstable branch, it gets tested, then you want it on master - but can't push it there!

Comment: +1 nice answer - I hope you don't mind, but I updated my answer in the linked question to use `git rev-list --merges`, with attribution back to your answer here.

Comment: non-linear history outside of master is fine for me. When merging people will git merge --squash to get it into master.

Answer (score 1):

After much struggle on the sourceforge server here is what I got:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Author: Mathieu Malaterre
# This code is free software. It can be used and distributed under the
# same terms as git itself.
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482887/how-to-avoid-merge-branch-master-of-ssh-gdcm-git-sourceforge-net-gitroot-gdc
read rev_old rev_new refname

ref_to_check="refs/heads/master"

if [ "$refname" = "$ref_to_check" ]
then
  merge_bases=`git merge-base ${rev_old} ${rev_new}`
  if [ "$merge_bases" != "$rev_old" ]
  then
    echo "Non fastward is disallowed"
    exit 1
  fi
  # non-fast-forward case:
  git rev-list --parents $merge_bases..$rev_new \
    | while read x; do
      set -- $x
      if [ "$#" != "2" ]
      then
        echo "Multiple parents: $x";
        exit 1
      fi;
    done
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: "==" is a bash-ism and so your script will only work on servers, where `/bin/sh` is, in fact, bash. You should change "==" to single "="...

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me! It protects selected branches against forced push and deletes.

```
#!/bin/sh

_REFNAME="$(echo "${1}" | sed -e 's,[^/]\+/,,g')"
_OLDREF="${2}"
_NEWREF="${3}"

_PROTECTED_LIST=( 'master' 'develop' )

_PROTECTED=false
for ref in "${_PROTECTED_LIST[@]}"; do
   if [[ "${ref}" == "${_REFNAME}" ]]; then
      _PROTECTED=true
   fi;
done;

echo ""
echo "#################### YOUR PROJECT NAME ####################"
echo "Branch: ${_REFNAME}"
echo "Old ref: ${_OLDREF}"
echo "New ref: ${_NEWREF}"
echo ""

_SUCCESS=true
if ${_PROTECTED}; then
   _GITOUT="$(git merge-base ${_OLDREF} ${_NEWREF} 2>/dev/null)"
   if [[ -n "${_GITOUT}" && "${_GITOUT}" != "${_OLDREF}" ]]; then
      echo "ERROR! You can't force the push on this branch!"
      _SUCCESS=false
   fi;
   if [[ -n "$(echo "${_NEWREF}" | sed -n -e '/^0\+$/p')" ]]; then
      echo "ERROR! You can't delete this branch!"
      _SUCCESS=false
   fi;
fi;

if ${_SUCCESS}; then
   echo "SUCCESS! :-)"
   echo "See you later?"
   echo ""
   exit 0
fi;

echo ""
exit 1
```